# Custom control event fire multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using [CheckBoxComboBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and?fid=476622&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=26#xx0xx) custom control. I try to use the DropDownClose event as:

```
var customerTypeFilterPanel = new Panel
   {
           AutoSize = true
   };

var ChkboxCustomerTypeFilter = new CheckBoxComboBox
            {
                Name = "chkcboCustomerTypeFilter",
                Width = 180,
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
            };
customerTypeFilterPanel.Controls.Add(ChkboxCustomerTypeFilter);
this.Controls.Add(customerTypeFilterPanel);
  ChkboxCustomerTypeFilter.DropDownClosed+= chkcboCustomerTypeFilter_DropDownClose;
```

Then close event:

```
    private void chkcboCustomerTypeFilter_DropDownClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            ...code here
            }
```

But I have an issue. The `DropDownClosed` triggers when the dropdown opens and when it closes.

How can I activate it only when it closes? Regards

Comment: TIL codeproject is still online :-) (somewhat)

Comment: Please make a minimal, complete, verifyable example. What you posted is a few orders of magnitude to big for us to read through | Also please give us the full code of the event and the funcion that registers the event. That might tell us something. | Finally, as this is a 3rd party tool made non-professionally, there might well be a bug in it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the CheckBoxComboBox; try putting a breakpoint in your event handler and trace back to where the event was triggered to see why